# glossaries: endless compile loop due to constantly changing page references

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

I am using `latexmk` with a custom rule for the `glossaries` package which calls `makeglossaries` to process the glossaries (using `xindy`). Acronyms are used as well. This processing ends up in an endless loop until `latexmk` reaches the maximum number of iterations.

My rule in the `latexmkrc` file is:

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries');
sub makeglossaries {
    system("makeglossaries \"$_[0]\"");
}
```

What I am seeing in the logs, after all required steps to actually build the correct document have been done, is the following pattern:

```
------------
Run number 5 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder  "thesis.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
...
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'thesis.pdf'
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [thesis.bcf thesis.bib]
Rule 'cusdep glo gls thesis': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.glo'
------------
Run number 5 of rule 'cusdep glo gls thesis'
------------
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'cusdep glo gls thesis'...
For rule 'cusdep glo gls thesis', running '&do_cusdep( makeglossaries )' ...
makeglossaries version 2.20 (2016-12-16)
...
Markup written into file "thesis.acr".
...
Markup written into file "thesis.gls".
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.gls'
------------
Run number 6 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder  "thesis.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
...
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'thesis.pdf'
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [thesis.bcf thesis.bib]
Rule 'cusdep glo gls thesis': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.glo'
------------
Run number 6 of rule 'cusdep glo gls thesis'
------------
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'cusdep glo gls thesis'...
For rule 'cusdep glo gls thesis', running '&do_cusdep( makeglossaries )' ...
...
Markup written into file "thesis.acr".
...
Markup written into file "thesis.gls".
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.gls'
```

`latexmk` sees that the `glo` file was changes, reruns `makeglossaries`, this changes the `gls` file, reruns `pdflatex` and so on...

When manually performing the repeating steps and checking the file checksums  I am seeing the following pattern:

```
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder  "thesis.tex" > /dev/null
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> md5sum thesis.glo thesis.gls
bb535a43a7b428821282a726370b52a7  thesis.glo
d31c2154df7d635bdc5340f78416b182  thesis.gls
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> makeglossaries thesis > /dev/null
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> md5sum thesis.glo thesis.gls
bb535a43a7b428821282a726370b52a7  thesis.glo
48b2f195a653372cec8ba2aa5657f021  thesis.gls
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder  "thesis.tex" > /dev/null
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> md5sum thesis.glo thesis.gls
a773f7fa5296db7f65f9c5dada9160df  thesis.glo
48b2f195a653372cec8ba2aa5657f021  thesis.gls
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> makeglossaries thesis > /dev/null
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> md5sum thesis.glo thesis.gls
a773f7fa5296db7f65f9c5dada9160df  thesis.glo
d31c2154df7d635bdc5340f78416b182  thesis.gls
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder  "thesis.tex" > /dev/null
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> md5sum thesis.glo thesis.gls
bb535a43a7b428821282a726370b52a7  thesis.glo
d31c2154df7d635bdc5340f78416b182  thesis.gls
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> makeglossaries thesis > /dev/null
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> md5sum thesis.glo thesis.gls
bb535a43a7b428821282a726370b52a7  thesis.glo
48b2f195a653372cec8ba2aa5657f021  thesis.gls
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder  "thesis.tex" > /dev/null
languitar@jaco ~/thesis (master)> md5sum thesis.glo thesis.gls
a773f7fa5296db7f65f9c5dada9160df  thesis.glo
48b2f195a653372cec8ba2aa5657f021  thesis.gls
```

**Edit:**
Yikes, this is caused by an extreme edge case with glossaries and the page referencing. The following screenshots illustrate the problem:

Things somehow end up in this situation inside the glossary of the document:
[image]

So the page reference for "system resource" is wrong because of the usage of this term in the description of "virtual resource". So LaTeX requests a rerun and after `makeglossaries` and `pdflatex` I end up with:

[image]

Now, because of the changes from range to individual pages, the text for "virtual resource" is relayouted differently and hence the page number changes and the circle starts again.

Is there a real solution to this apart from rephrasing paragraphs to avoid the additional/removed linebreak?

Comment: an even worse (to my eyes) flaw is the separation of the headword "virtual resource" from its definition by a page break.  that shouldn't happen, but if it is suppressed, it might possibly lead to a page break after the index "v" which would be worse.  there may be a way to insinuate an explicit page break into the stream as an alternative to rewriting a definition; by this i mean a dummy entry that is present in the main tex file, not added later in the glossary file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's another thing I have to fix, but the original problem could still arise with a fix.